# Error handling for async functions without callback or promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am using a third party library which does some async operations but need to try catch error on it. It doesn't have a callback and no promises for async function. Does anyone know about any library or a way to catch those errors? I am trying to do something like this.

```
var asyncLib = require( 'asyncLib' );

try {
   asyncLib.doSomething();
} catch( e ) {
    //I want to catch if doSomething throws some error
    // But it doesn't because it's using async resources.
}
```

Comment: And this function doesn't have a callback or isn't a promise? Is it bubbling up as an uncaught exception?

Comment: Yes, it's neither a promise nor a callback

Comment: Which error you want to catch??? Every error?

Comment: Does it matter what error it is? For reference it's related to file not found.

Comment: "It doesn't have a callback and no promises for async function" then my suggestion would be to use a different library. This question is incredibly vague... How do you determine what happens after the async operation? Do you have any control over that code at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting to handle errors that are not coming to you through the usual channels, you can try running your code within a domain. This will enable catching error events that are going unhandled:

```
var d = require('domain').create();
d.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error(err.stack);
});
d.run(function() {
  yourCode();
});
```

Or if this is something domain error handling can't deal with:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.error(err.stack);
});
```

Of course, you wouldn't want to just log and continue as in my example, but you get the picture.